# Phonegap: JS call to Java Method works only in 1 case

Tags: java, javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on a Phonegap Project where i am at the stage of extending the base capabilities of Phonegap with a custom Plugin. The stupid problem i am having is getting the Plugin to react correctly. The Plugin if called with the 'echo' parameter should answer giving back its matched parameter name, the same goes for 'echo2'.

**The strange part:**

'echo' returns the expected answer (it executes the success callback) whereas the 'echo2' variant returns the error callback. Seriously running out of ideas...

**The JS Definitions:** Identical functions (only the 4th Parameter is different)

```
window.echo = function(str, callback) {
            cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
                    callback('Nothing to echo.');
                    }, 'Echo', 'echo', [str]);
       };

window.sync = function(str, callback) {
            cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
                    callback('Nothing to echo.');
                    }, 'Echo', 'echo2', [str]);
       };
```

**The JS Calls on these functions:**

```
echo('Echo String', function(echoValue) {
      alert(echoValue);
});

sync('Sync String', function(echoValue) {
      alert(echoValue);
});
```

**Java Class:**

```
public class Echo extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        switch(action) {

            case "echo":    String message = args.getString(0);
                            this.echo("Call on: Echo.echo()" + message, callbackContext);
                            return true;

            case "echo2":   String message = args.getString(0);
                            this.echo("Call on: Echo.echo2()" + message, callbackContext);
                            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void echo(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) { 
            callbackContext.success(message);
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, for one, `echo` and `echo2` should be in double quotes in your switch, not single quotes (in the Java file). And, instead of `String.message`, I think you want `String message`. Third, this makes no sense, because the only case your could get an error callback is if `message` is non-null and non-empty, but that *can't* happen in the code snippet you gave

Comment: Yep, double quotes and String message updated. Thanks @ColinMorelli. The error callback within the class would come into play later on... rebuilt with same outcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all those having a similar problem, here is some information on why this did not work:

**Firstly:** The Code works fine - the problem doesn't lie here.

**Where's the fault?**

When i asked the question, the Java **Class was named Echo** which worked when the class method  was being called. Trying to call any other method fails because the

> Phonegap Build Service does not allow direct includes of plugins

**BUT** in my case it still partially worked because the Java Class Echo happens to be a standard Plugin that Phonegap Build included for me.

This Echo Plugin being included by Phonegap Build happens to have a method echo which resulted in a success callback, obviously.

**After further reading:**

A tool called plugman (also developed by Adobe) handles the custom plugin implementation by adding the created plugin to the phonegap project ... i am still testing and learning this, the official information (and only information i found) is available here:

► [Leads to the deprecated pluginstall tool](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins-contributing)

► [Plugman Tool Repo - GitHub](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman)